# О режимах наложения css

Tags: css

У меня есть модальное окно, и требуется сделать, чтобы модальных окон было 2+
У окна есть background rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7). Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при появлении второго модального окна, его background не смешивался с первым и область не становилась ещё темнее? В то же самое время, чтобы само первое модальное окно становилось темнее.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то простыми средствами CSS это не сделать. Можно поиграться, конечно, с [blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode), но не думаю что поможет.

Comment: Что-бы вам помось нужно добавить ваш код

Comment: Возможно, стоит удалять у первого окна фон, а новое окно будет с новым фоном поверх всего. После закрытия второго окна, фон будет перемещен за первое окно, и как заметили выше, нужен какой-то код, чтобы понимать что вы хотите сделать